# Are there any English words where the EA grapheme represents a schwa sound?

Tags: pronunciation

There are many graphemes that can represent the schwa sound, several of which start with an E:

- EI as in FOREIGN
- EO as in SURGEON or DUNGEON

I am curious if the grapheme EA can also represent a schwa sound.  The only possibility I can think of is OCEAN (/ˈoʊ.ʃən/).

- The O represents a Long O sound.
- The C can represent an /ʃ/, as in words like APPRECIATE, OFFICIATE, DEPRECIATE, SPECIES and ASSOCIATE).
- The EA could represent a /ə/, as EI, EO and EU do.
- And the N often represents an /n/.

But it's also possible that the CE represents an /ʃ/, as it does in CRETACEOUS, CURVACEOUS, CRUSTACEAN, and ECHINACEA.  Then the A by itself would represent the schwa, not the EA.

I am trying to think of any other words where EA represents a schwa.  The closest I can find is the EAU in BUREAUCRAT.

Are there any English words where the EA grapheme represents a schwa sound?

Comment: Which accent/dialect/country? Possibly "forehead" in some accents but we're going to get deep into a debate about [reduced vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English) and you'll wish you never asked the question.

Comment: If "surgeon" is acceptable for "EO", is "sergeant" acceptable for "EA"? (Not sure I'd accept either, personally, hence not posting as an answer!)

Comment: I would definitely accept sergeant fot EA... if you add that, I'd accept it as an answer!

Comment: One must accept the fact that in English spelling it is often impossible to reliably assign pieces of the word's pronunciation to pieces of the word's spelling (or vice versa).

Comment: Or, as every honest ESL teacher tells their students, English spelling has no reliable relation to English pronunciations, meaning that both have to be learned, separately, for each word.. Just like Chinese.

Comment: I often pronounce "near" as "nurr" (/nɚ/), but maybe that's just me.

Comment: *Then the E by itself would represent the schwa, not the EA.* You meant "the A by itself", right?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan ah yes, thank you for the correction!  fixed it...

Comment: What a dolt I am, I pronounce that word for heat-treating milk *etc* close to "past-your-eyes", definitely not a schwa.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark removed it as the question stands without it... now off to study its syllabization!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd accept it myself, but if "surgeon" and "dungeon" are acceptable for "EO", then for "EA"

> [Sergeant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sergeant)

might fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wiktionary, in GenAmE, [laryngeal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laryngeal#Pronunciation) and [pharyngeal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pharyngeal#Pronunciation) may be pronounced with no sound corresponding to the `e`. So you could say that `ea` is pronounced [ə]. (But it could be argued that really the `e` is silent and the `a` on its own is pronounced [ə].)

Comment: Yes, In those cases it might well be that those speakers analyse the < e > as there to make the < g > ‘soft’. Again making it really a case of just the < a > representing a schwa. (So the < e > is interpreted as part of a < ge > digraph, not an < ea > one)